# How to evaluate Spock @IgnoreIf using a method

Tags: groovy, spock

According to the following article:

https://dzone.com/articles/spocklight-ignore

you should be able to evaluate the Spock @IgnoreIf annotation using a static method. I tried the isOsWindows() method exactly as in the article, and got the following:

```
org.spockframework.runtime.extension.ExtensionException: Failed to evaluate @IgnoreIf condition
...
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: MySpec$__spock_feature_1_3_closure1.isOsWindows() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Does anyone have any insight on this? I really want to just set a true/false per spec, I don't need any of the os/system properties listed in the other examples.

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

The example is a little outdated `Code written with Spock 0.7-groovy-2`, if you want to use a static method then you need use the qualified version `ClassName.method()`.

```
package com.mrhaki.spock

import spock.lang.*

class SampleRequiresSpec extends Specification {

    private static boolean isOsWindows() {
        System.properties['os.name'] == 'windows'
    }

    @IgnoreIf({ SampleRequiresSpec.isOsWindows() })
    def "run only if run on non-windows operating system"() {
        expect:
        true
    }
}
```

If you only want to run on windows, then there are some convenience functions built in (Spock 1.+).

- Operating System `@IgnoreIf({ os.windows || os.linux || os.macOs || os.solaris || os.other })`
- Java Version `@IgnoreIf({ jvm.java5 || jvm.java6 || jvm.java7 || jvm.java8 || jvm.java9 })`
- Environment Variable `@IgnoreIf({ !env.containsKey("FOOBARBAZ") })` `@IgnoreIf({ env["FOOBARBAZ"] == 'false'})`
- SystemProperty `@IgnoreIf({ !sys.contains("java.version") })` `@IgnoreIf({ sys["java.version"] == '1.6' })`

Comment: I probably wasn't clear - I don't really want to know anything about the OS, I just want to access a global variable or constant - using a method would be a workaround for this. I'll try the qualified name, thanks.

Comment: @orbfish if you want to access a constant just use the qualified name, you don't need a helper method. And also please accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Using the qualified version of the static method works for me.  What is confusing though is that the unqualified version of the static method works too, but ONLY if the tests are executed within IntelliJ.  Once they are executed via something like gradle, this error appears.